# Find first row with condition after each row satisfying another condition

Tags: python, pandas

in pandas I have the following data frame:

```
a b
0 0
1 1
2 1
0 0
1 0
2 1
```

Now I want to do the following:
Create a new column c, and for each row where a = 0 fill c with 1. Then c should be filled with 1s until the first row after each column fulfilling that, where b = 1 (and here im hanging), so the output should look like this:

```
a b c
0 0 1
1 1 1
2 1 0
0 0 1
1 0 1
2 1 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: What should happen for a row where `a=0` and `b=1`? If you're already in the mode of writing 1 into `c`, and you encounter that row, do you continue writing 1 into `c`? Do you stop? If you're not in the mode of writing 1 to `c` and you encounter that row, do you start writing 1 to `c`?

Comment: thanks ely. i'll first try jezraels solution or sth. with apply, as my use case is a bit more complicated than this simplificatino here, I am actually not so sure about c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need:

```
df['c'] = df.groupby(df.a.eq(0).cumsum())['b'].cumsum().le(1).astype(int)
print (df)
   a  b  c
0  0  0  1
1  1  1  1
2  2  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  1  0  1
5  2  1  1
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.a.eq(0).cumsum())
0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: a, dtype: int32
```

Comment: ok, thanks. i'll see if I can apply that to my exact use case.